# Multiple queries in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

If I run this query in rails console,

```
def c
  ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  users = User.all
  members = Member.where(id: ids).includes(:locations)
  user_id_to_member_id_mapping = {} # Not empty. hash that gives member_id for each userid  
  users.each do |user|
    puts members.find_by(id: user_id_to_member_id_mapping[user.id]).location
  end
end
```

multiple queries (Member object queries) are fired (one for each value of `i`). Are the members already in memory (`members` variable)? How can I get the data needed above to make a single query?

```
Member Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE `members`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) AND `members`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ProfileAnswer Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `profile_answers`.* FROM `profile_answers` WHERE `profile_answers`.`member_id` = 1
  Member Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE `members`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) AND `members`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ProfileAnswer Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `profile_answers`.* FROM `profile_answers` WHERE `profile_answers`.`member_id` = 2
  Member Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE `members`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) AND `members`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  ProfileAnswer Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `profile_answers`.* FROM `profile_answers` WHERE `profile_answers`.`member_id` = 3
  Member Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE `members`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) AND `members`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
  ProfileAnswer Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `profile_answers`.* FROM `profile_answers` WHERE `profile_answers`.`member_id` = 4
  Member Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE `members`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) AND `members`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
  ProfileAnswer Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `profile_answers`.* FROM `profile_answers` WHERE `profile_answers`.`member_id` = 5
  Member Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE `members`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) AND `members`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
```

I can't use `member.each` as the iterator is on a different condition.

Comment: What's `location`?

Comment: location is a different object.

Comment: Please properly indent code samples when posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would be firing a query for each  `Member` load because of the line

```
members.find_by(id: ids[i]).location
```

Here you have explicitly used `find_by` which is firing a query for each member also for location.

If reducing the query is priority then you may make use of ruby here

```
def c
  ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  users = User.all
  members = Member.where(id: ids).includes(:locations)
  user_id_to_member_id_mapping = {} # Not empty. hash that gives member_id for each userid  
  users.each do |user|
   puts members.find { |m| m.id == user_id_to_member_id_mapping[user.id] }&.location
end
```

Please note this would impact your performance if the Members count is very high.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah the member count is huge.

Comment: what would be count?

Comment: 50k users 30k memebrs

Comment: it won't compromise much if members are 30k

Answer (score 0):

By your code, it is supposed that you have model `Location` with table name 'profile_answers' table.

Member has many profile_answers & has many locations through profile_answers .

Then,

```
members = Members.includes(profile_answers: :locations).where(id: ids)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. updated the question. the question is why multiple member queries.

Answer (score 0):

`members` is a scope. `members.find_by` executes a query on scope. Hence an `N+1`.

You want instead:

```
members =
  Member.
    where(id: ids).
    includes(:locations).
    to_a # greedy load

puts members.map(&:location) # or whatever
```

Answer (score -1):

If the `location` is a model, you should use includes; `includes` will run a query to get your initial `model`'s data and the included models

```
program = Program.first
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
members = Members.includes(:locations).where(id: ids)
```

Now when you get the first members, calling its location will be read from the memory.

If the `location` is a column and you want to load all members, you can do:

```
program = Program.first
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
members = Members.where(id: ids)
locations = members.pluck(:location)
```

And finally, if you don't want to use the members, you can do:

```
program = Program.first
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
locations = Members.where(id: ids).pluck(:location)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. yeah added includes but I am asking about query on member.

Comment: okay; so now you've loaded the members in the memory, the `find_by_id` will reload that user so you should remove it. you need to do: `locations = []` `members.each { |member| locations << member.location }`; this will load the locations from the memory instead of the database - or simple: `locations = members.map(&:location)`

Comment: I guess `map(&:location)` is the worst you can do.

Comment: @SebastianPalma and why is that ?

Comment: Updated the question. Cannot use iterator on member as mentioned in question.

Comment: @AbhishekNicchanametla your code makes no sense to be honest; can you post the models + relationships so we can help you ?

Comment: Ok. Member has many locations through profile answers. And also Member has many users. I need the mapping of user and location. i.e I need for given users what is the location.

Comment: OK. Maybe you can do something like that: `User.includes(members: :locations).each { |user| user.member.location }`; if your relationships are correct, this should work :-)

Comment: Tried it already but the number of records of users and members is huge. Also, the size of each record of member is also big. Sio performance is bad as we are loading lot of unnecessary data.

Comment: Then paginate the data, get the users for specific members only; not sure what you really need here, but this is something that you can start from.

Comment: Member.all.includes(:locations).select(:id).map{|m| [m.id, m.location]}.to_h
 This query is taking the least time as we are getting rid of unwanted data at sql level itself and creating active record object with only id.